# How do you design an image for Codename One TouchCommand?

Tags: codenameone

I am 2 days in experimenting with Codename One and Mobile development in general and tested out some basic navigation and features so far. Now I want to work on the look and feel of the app. 
I looked at the 9-border vid which was helpful, but not sure of the best way to add an image for the touchCommand that takes 3 tabs on that bar ( Example: home, profile, settings.. Similar to how instagram's TouchCommand is at the bottom of the app).
If I add the image, it does not line up with my Commands.

[image]

What is the best way to approach this to ensure the "TouchCommand" image appears as one, but is broken up to 3 parts for each individual commands when pressed, home, profile and settings? I might be asking this all wrong, forgive me as this is all new to me.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
This is what was done.
In `Theme -> Constants added commandBehavior= bar` . This gives the default bar at the bottom. Created in photoshop a new bar `300x80` and added it to the `TouchCommand`. (See ScreenShot 1). Took this bar and broke it up in photoshop into 3 different buttons for the `tab press` etc. In GUI Builder, added `Home, Profile, Settings` in the `commands`. Added the image to `Press Icon` for Home and it didnt line up (screenshot 2). Very Frustrating to design layouts. I am hoping there is a much better technique as I am still experimenting with Codename one?

What is unclear to me, is I cant find any documentation on how to approach this and what the dimensions of each image should be as it seems that codename one has issue aligning them. I am assuming the steps would be to create the background image and add the icons as interactive layers for the user. I really care for the image being pressed and changes color like the instagram example. I dont see a way to do this in codename one GUI builder and themes.

[image]
[image]

EDIT:

Okay, I have decided to use tabs instead of the bar at the bottom. If I add my image to it, I get the results (screeshot 3). Is this the right method to use to accompolish what I want? If so, I dont see a way yet to alter this to become what I want :( .

[image]

Plus adding the background, shows one size in the display and looks different in the simulator. (screeshot4)
[image]

Answered Here: [How do you get ActionBar from SocialBoo theme to show up in your GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546122/how-do-you-get-actionbar-from-socialboo-theme-to-show-up-in-your-gui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs are customized individually so the border should apply for an individual tab to create the background. The foreground element is the icon which you define in the Tabs component itself thru the icons property which allows you to define 3 icons for the 3 tabs (assuming you use the GUI builder). If you add the tabs via `addTab` in the code you can specify an icon there.

Comment: Do you have any video Tutorial with methods how to use your own images to design something in the screen shot above? I am using the 'bar' at the bottom and added 3 commands. For each command I added the state image for rollover, default and pressed. My Images does not line up... Are there any guidelines to follow so I can create the images with the right size and get them looking smooth as the above screenshot?

Comment: Make sure the images are of the exact same size with transparent pixel padding. A screenshot of your result would be helpful to guide you.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question. The issue is unclear to me what size I should be using so they fit perfectly. I tried both 'bar' and 'tabs' . The tabs might be better, but dont see how to use the designer to make it to how I want it.. Assuming will need to use the unselected,selected, press and disable features in the Themes somehow. I design all my images on photoshop, but need guidance on dimensions and how to use them to get what I want... Once I understand this, I think it will be smooth sailing from there as I really want the UI to look good.

Comment: The gradient is breaking for you because you didn't cut the 9-pieces correctly, you should get the lines as close as possible to one another: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-9-piece-image-border.html if all tabs have an image of the exact same size (I suggest using a multi image for all) they will align perfectly. To add a line on top of the selected tab just define a pressed/selected style and cut a 9-piece border for that with the additional selection marker.

Comment: The 9-piece border helped with the sizing but was unable to get my result like the example above. With the lack of documentation on this topic I can see a way to achieve it without going grey.. I have have tested enough, moving to another tool as UI is important in my app..Thanks for your help tho.

Comment: We have a huge developer guide http://codenameone.com/developer-guide.html tons of videos http://codenameone.com/how-do-i.html demos and javadocs http://codenameone.com/download.html huge online course http://udemy.com/codenameone101/ 
There is documentation and what you are trying to do is trivial in Codename One.

Comment: You say trivial, I say overlooked and fundamental. I downloaded most of the app for IOS and Android that were created with Codename one and all the UI's were poor. You can have the best idea and logic with a poor UI your app will still fail so it equally as important.. I dont want to design eveything it photoshop only to realized I have to redo the images cause it doesnt fit or line up. There need to be a guide on how to do that. BTW: I looked at all the "How To" and Doc, Helpful in some areas but not this.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/il/app/qmarkets-mobile/id733539152?mt=8 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.brunstad.bmm Since we have hundreds of published apps somehow I doubt you downloaded most of them. 9-piece images are a fundamental concept in Android design as well and scale rather nicely when used properly.

Comment: yes, I saw qmarkets not the other, but those are great.. I got my list from http://www.codenameone.com/gallery.html . The scaling is very helpful, I like that feature..Okay, maybe I shouldnt use tabs to design this, maybe it some other feature? I saw something similar in the socialboo theme, but it is not tabs, is it commandbehavior Bar? . I will give it another shot tonight.

Comment: and FYI: I took out the check mark because I didnt get a correct answer to my questions (would reinstate it when that happens), doesnt mean you have to equal that with a downvote...Although I gave u an upvote for your answer. Eye 4 an eye?

Comment: Its unrelated to that. I got a bit upset with the spirit of discussion here, we are trying to be helpful and I felt you took this in a direction that I didn't like. I tried to undo the downvote which is indeed petty but it won't let me do that for two hours so I'll try to do this tomorrow.

Comment: No probs. Its all good. As I said this whole mobile dev is very new and a lot to take in. Decided with this tool so I dont have to develop  for 2 different OS and will def. give it a fair chance..I really want to know how to create that..doesnt seems like tabs is the right solution tho. I was able to create the ActionBar to what I want in Android only but wanted to do this in codenameone. The functionaily of my app is secondary as that isnt the issue for me. I just want the visual look and feel to be what i have in my head..That is very important, given the type of app I am designing.