# How do you get ActionBar from SocialBoo theme to show up in your GUI?

Tags: codenameone

Ok. Starting over with this. I see that the `SocialBoo` theme has something similar in what I want to achieve. If I find that I can work and improve. I Added a new `socialboo theme` and created blank GUI. Assumed it would be a `Commandbehavior` but that didnt do the trick, so did adding `tabs`. Seems like those components are not for that specific bar... However did notice another issue.

How do I get the social `actionbar` as displayed in the `socialboo theme`? (Screen shot). Assuming those images etc are part of the default theme, right.

[image]

Also, If I create a `TouchCommand = bar, title or native`. It displays fine in Gingerbread but not ICS. DO you know why is that? (screen shot)
[image]

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those images aren't a part of the theme, they are a part of the specific demo. If you add a Tabs component to the center of the border layout UI you will get thee tabs where the "icon" property will allow you to customize the unselected icon and you can customize the selected icon as well. You can see the full source/resource file of the social boo demo in the docs and demos zip in the [download section](http://codenameone.com/download.html).

Generally customizing commands is a bit complex because of platform specific constraints, when running on an Actual Android 4 device we use the native ActionBar by default to provide the experience Android users are used to. This is hard for us to simulate so you will only see this properly in the device build. I suggest not relying on commands, it seems that what you are trying to achieve is easily doable with tabs and its possible that's why you had difficulties in your other question.

Comment: Sweet. Didnt realize you were a co-founder of codename one so I will def. take your word in using the tabs instead of customizing commands.. Getting the demos helps a great deal seeing it in action as well as knowledge on the image sizes etc. I feel much better now, and creating this shouldnt be an issue anymore. Hopefully by the time I am done, it may be featured on your site !! BTW: It is very cool that you will take the time to reply to user's concerns !! Keep it up.